# MVC4 EF 4.1 occassional "Connection must be opened" error when showing multiple images in a View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image, ef-code-first, structuremap

My current app is using .NET MVC3 with EF 4.1 Code First and an Oracle back end. Everything works fine practically all the time except in one scenario, which is where we have a View that displays multiple images. Sometimes all images are loaded fine, other times some of them fail to load and I get one of 2 error messages - "The connection was not closed" or "Connection must be opened". The image are stored in the db as BLOBs and not on the server's file system.
I have a view model containing a collection of Documents (which are images) and use an EditorTemplate to render the collection in the View. The rendered code makes a call to a Controller action to retrieve each image in the collection. Here's the Razor code that renders the collection:

Parent View:

```
<div  id="carousel1" class="data-carousel">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Documents)
</div>
```

Editor template:

```
<div>
    <img style="border: solid; border-color: lightgrey; border-width: thin" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Product", new {docId = Model.DocumentID, width = 250, height = 250})" alt=""/>           
</div>
```

so this code gets written to the browser

```
<img style="border: solid; border-color: lightgrey; border-width: thin" src="http://localhost:9613/Product/GetImage?docId=1&width=250&height=250" alt=""/>
<img style="border: solid; border-color: lightgrey; border-width: thin" src="http://localhost:9613/Product/GetImage?docId=2&width=250&height=250" alt=""/>
<img style="border: solid; border-color: lightgrey; border-width: thin" src="http://localhost:9613/Product/GetImage?docId=3&width=250&height=250" alt=""/>
<img style="border: solid; border-color: lightgrey; border-width: thin" src="http://localhost:9613/Product/GetImage?docId=4&width=250&height=250" alt=""/>
```

As you can see this creates a link that passes some params including the id to an action method which returns the image as a byte array:

```
public void GetImage(int docId, int width, int height)
{
    // Load image from database
    var doc = productRepository.Documents.SingleOrDefault(f => f.DocumentID == docId);
    var image = doc.FileContent;

    new WebImage(image)
   .Resize(width, height, true, true)
   .Crop(1, 1)
   .Write();
}
```

I'm pretty sure what's happening is that the Controller action is being called for each image (potentially up to 10), and the db connection isn't closed before the next request comes in. I tried creating a method on the repository that creates a new instance of the Context in a "using" statement to see if this would improve things but it didn't.
So is there anything I can do? Should I be looking at the new async maybe, or is there some other pattern I can use to retrieve multiple images in a View?

TIA

**EDIT:**

The application is hosted in IIS7 with it's own application pool in Classic pipeline mode. I use StructureMap as an IoC container so this controls the creation and lifetime of the DbContext. The instantiation happens when the Controller gets instantiated:

SM setup:

```
public static class StructuremapMvc 
{
    public static void Start() 
    {
        var container = (IContainer)IoC.Initialize();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SmDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}

public static IContainer Initialize() 
{
    ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
    {
        x.Scan(scan =>
        {
            scan.TheCallingAssembly();
            scan.WithDefaultConventions();
        });
        x.For<IProductRepository>().Use<ProductRepository>();
        x.For<IProductContext>().Use<ProductContext>();
    });

    return ObjectFactory.Container;
}
```

Controller:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private readonly IProductRepository productRepository;

    public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    public void GetImage(int docId, int width, int height)
    {
        // Load image from database
        var doc = productRepository.Documents.SingleOrDefault(f => f.DocumentID == docId);
        var image = doc.FileContent;

        new WebImage(image)
       .Resize(width, height, true, true)
       .Crop(1, 1)
       .Write();
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Repository:

```
public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
    private readonly IProductContext productContext;

    public ProductRepository(IProductContext productContext)
    {
        productContext = productContext;
    }

    public IQueryable<Document> Documents
    {
        get { return productContext.Documents; }
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Context:

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext, IProductContext
{
    // DbSets
    public IDbSet<Document> Documents { get; set; }

    public void SetModified(object entity)
    {
        Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }   

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // etc.
    }

    // etc. 
}
```

Comment: how is `prodContext` instantiated?  When is it disposed?

Comment: @StanK Hi Stan see my edit above, I'm assuming EF disposes the context when GetImage on the Controller returns and the request goes out of scope

Comment: You shouldn't assume that. Try specifying that the context is http context scoped. I couldn't find a feature to callback when object is deactivated by IoC in structure map (Ninject has OnDeactivation for that). If that doesn't help, try moving instantiating/disposing that context outside of structure map.